# Switch Statement not updating the Document.getElementById()

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Switch Statement Which looks like this.

```
switch (rsCash.length){
case 1:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash + "Gp";
    break;
case 2:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash + "Gp";
    break;
case 3:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash + "Gp";
    break;
case 4:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash.substring(0,cut1) + "k";
    break;
case 5:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash.substring(0,cut2) + "k";
    break;
case 6:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash.substring(0,cut3) + "k";
    break;
case 7:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash.substring(0,cut1) + "M";
    break;
case 8:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash.substring(0,cut2) + "M";
    break;
case 9:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash.substring(0,cut3) + "M";
    break;
case 10:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash.substring(0,cut4) + "M";
    break;
case 11:
    document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash.substring(0,cut5) + "M";
    break;
```

}

And when the rsCash variable Changes it doesn't update.

The HTML is.

```
<h1 id="RsMoney">RsCash:<b id="cash3">0 Gp</b></h1>
```

I have tried putting the switch statement in a function that gets called every second but it still doesn't work

i have copied and pasted the whole code in a JavaScript lint and it found no Errors and Google Chrome has found no Errors either

The Variable changes by this function here.

```
function OpenCrate(){
if(Crates != 0){
var RewardNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 15)+ 1);
switch (RewardNumber){
case 1:
    rsCash = rsCash + 200000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "$200k was found!";
    break;
case 2:
    rsCash = rsCash + 25000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "$15 was found!";
    break;
case 3:
    rsCash = rsCash + 5000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "5k was found!";
    break;
case 4:
    rsCash = rsCash + 500000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "500k was found!";
    break;
case 5:
    rsCash = rsCash + 75000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "75k was found!";
    break;
case 6:
    rsCash = rsCash + 5000000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "5m was found!";
    break;
case 7:
    rsCash = rsCash + 275000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "275k was found!";
    break;
case 8:
    rsCash = rsCash + 5000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "5k was found!";
    break;
case 9:
    rsCash = rsCash + 15000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "15k was found!";
    break;
case 10:
    rsCash = rsCash + 8000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "8k was found!";
    break;
case 11:
    rsCash = rsCash + 35000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "35k was found!";
    break;
case 12:
    rsCash = rsCash + 125000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "125k was found!";
    break;
case 13:
    rsCash = rsCash + 80000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "80k was found!";
    break;
case 14:
    rsCash = rsCash + 600000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "600k was found!";
    break;
case 15:
    rsCash = rsCash + 12000;
    document.getElementById("Log").innerHTML = "12k was found!";
    break;
}
```

Comment: And how does the `rsCash` variable change ?

Comment: Just Updated it with the function that changes the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rsCash` is a number:

```
rsCash = rsCash + 200000;
```

but you're trying to take the length of it:

```
switch (rsCash.length) ...
```

You can't do that - you get `undefined`, so none of your `case`s fire.  You need to convert `rsCash` to a string before taking its length; something like this:

```
switch (rsCash.toString().length) ...
```

Comment: Now i am getting an error message in google chrome saying " Error: Cannot set prperty 'innerHTML' of null and it is saying that for the line 'document.getElementById("cash3").innerHTML = rsCash + "Gp";' in the switch statement